# Talend tRestRequest escape character JSON

Tags: json, base64, talend

I'm meeting a problem with Talend Software.

I use a service in order to retrieve information about user from a LDAP. Among information, there is a jpegPhoto (bytes array). 
The original photo is in Base64 format, for example :

> "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABA..."

When I call the service, the JSON Request displays :

> "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABA...."

Yet I've put a tLogRow element just before the tRestRequest, and it displays :

> "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABA..."

I don't know why this error occurs :/

Any idea ?

Comment: *When I call the service, the JSON Request displays :

\/9j\/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASA

Comment: All of those are the same... what are you trying to do here? It might be better to include screenshots of your jobs and example values at each point.

Comment: Hello ydaetskcoR. Yes, all of those are the same, that's why I've added a comment to correct my mistake.

To avoid this problem, I've decided to write my own JSON request, and I manage to get my base 64 photo